# JS Function "not defined"

Tags: javascript, class, toggle, classiejs

I'm fairly new to JS, and I have been looking around to find answers unsuccessfully. It may well be trivial but I must not be looking at the problem from the right angle.

I have a JS function using classie and scroll event working well (toggling classes). 
Now I wanted to add this following one but both FF and Chrome's consoles tell me the function isn't defined... and I couldn't find why. This snippet is in the < head > of a wordpress header template. The divs it should apply to are in the same header template (there are 2).

```
<script>
function openmenu() {
    var order = document.getElementsByClassName("menu-burger");
    var orderTotal = order.length;
    for(var i = 0; i < orderTotal ; i++){
        order[i].addEventListener("click", function ServeBurger() {
            Table13 = document.GetElementById("mobile-menu");
            classie.toggle(Table13, "show"));
            }
        , false);
    }
}
</script>
```

What am I doing wrong?
Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`GetElementById` should be `getElementById`

Comment: That's right -.-' Now I don't have "not defined" anymore but the function is not toggling classes... any idea why?

Comment: @LudoC: [Learn how to debug JavaScript](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/javascript-debugging)

Comment: @LudoC try to make a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) with your problem, and btw you make `Table13` global, it is bad practice. In your case it's better to to define one local variable without loop.